# Regex add quotes in Python so I can return Python Dictionary

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, dictionary

Using Python and Regex, I would like to add quotes to each word. Currently, I am only able to add quotes to a first index. When I loop through my end results, I get a string. Instead, I would like Python Dictionary. To solve this problem, I think adding quotes will help me get dictionary instead of a string. Can someone please guide me?

**Code**

```
raw = "[historic_list {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}historic_list {id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }historic_list {id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}time_statistics {job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'} UrlPairList {}]"

line_re = re.compile(r'\{[^\}]+\}')
records = line_re.findall(raw)

record_re = re.compile(
    r"""
            id:\s*\'(?P<id>[^']+)\'\s*
            startdate:\s*(?P<startdate>\d+)\s*
            numvaluelist:\s*(?P<numvaluelist>[\d\.]+)\s*
            datelist:\s*(?P<datelist>\d+)\s*
            """,
    re.X
    )

record_parsed = record_re.search(line_re.findall(raw)[0])
record_parsed.groupdict()
# {'startdate': '42521', 'numvaluelist': '0.1065599566767107', 'datelist': '42521', 'id': 'A(long) 11A'}

for record in records:
    record_parsed = record_re.search(record)
    print type(record)
```

**Current Output**

```
{id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}
{id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }
{id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}
```

**Desired Output** Everything in quotes

```
{'id': 'A(long) 11A' 'startdate': '42521' 'numvaluelist': '0.1065599566767107' 'datelist': '42521'}
{'id': 'A(short) 11B' 'startdate': '42521' 'numvaluelist': '0.0038113334533441123' 'datelist': '42521' }
{'id': 'B(long) 11C' 'startdate': '42521' 'numvaluelist': '20.061623176440904' 'datelist': '42521'}
```

Comment: Find the source of the data and kindly ask them to offer json serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to parse it using regular expressions. If you are matching each part so exactly as in your original, there's probably a more generic way.

```
import re
raw = "[historic_list {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}historic_list {id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }historic_list {id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}time_statistics {job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'} UrlPairList {}]"

line_re = re.compile(r'\{[^\}]+\}')
value_re = re.compile(r"(\w+): ('[^']*'|\S+)")

data = []
lines = line_re.findall(raw)
for line in lines:
    data_line = dict()
    values = re.findall(value_re, line)
    for (name, value) in values:
        if(value[-1] == '}'): value = value[:-1]  # to handle "foo}" without space
        if(value[:1] == "'"): value = value[1:-1]  # strip quotes
        data_line[name] = value
    data.append(data_line)

print data
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your end goal is to parse that textual data into Python dictionaries. Adding quotes is the way you've come up with to do that (presumably you're then planning to use `eval()` to parse it), but it's the long way around.

Instead, parse it directly. You don't even need a regex, and it is much clearer what you're doing. Here's a quick and dirty attempt.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

raw = "[historic_list {id: 'A(long) 11A' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.1065599566767107 datelist: 42521}historic_list {id: 'A(short) 11B' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 0.0038113334533441123 datelist: 42521 }historic_list {id: 'B(long) 11C' startdate: 42521 numvaluelist: 20.061623176440904 datelist: 42521}time_statistics {job_id: '' portfolio_id: '112341'} UrlPairList {}]"

record = OrderedDict()
records = []

tokens = iter(raw.split())
previous_token = ""

for token in tokens:
    if previous_token == "{id:":
        record["id"] = token.lstrip("'")
        # get the rest of the ID up to closing quote
        for token in tokens:
            record["id"] += " " + token
            if token.endswith("'"):
                record["id"] = record["id"].rstrip("'")
                break
    elif previous_token in ("startdate:", "numvaluelist:"):
        record["numvaluelist"] = token
    elif previous_token == "datelist:":
        record["datelist"] = token.partition("}")[0]
        # record is complete; start new one
        records.append(record)
        record = OrderedDict()
    previous_token = token
```

Once you have it as Python data, you can of course print it any way you like... including, just for fun, the format you asked for:

```
for record in records:
    print("{%s}" % ", ".join(repr(k) + ": " + repr(record[k]) for k in record))
```

Comment: Nice use of OrderedDict

Comment: Thought it would be nice to preserve the order just in case.